# LGPL - iOS App written in Swift with external Qt Library

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, lgpl

I have an app written in Swift 5 which uses an external static Qt library.
This library runs with an LGPL licence, so I must provide this App with an opportunity to make the library and the underlying Qt sources exchangeable/modifyable.

These are the contents of my current archived app:

[image]

Now to my question: How can I make an archive of this App, where all the libraries used and put under "Other Linker Flags" are separated of the executable app file?
Or do I need to find a completely new way to integrate these ressources into my app?

Comment: Open source doesn't mean that you have to attach the code to your program, but that you provide access to the code to the user. Also, unless you modified the code of Qt, you don't need to release that too. If you have a website or repository, just put your code there.

Comment: @musicamante My Project isnt open source and I cant make it open source either. The problem is, that I'm using Qt under an LGPL Licence, which says, I must provide a way for the user to exchange LGPL licenced components of my app. F.e to seperate the product of the app and the QT ressources or making the whole project open source (the later,  I can't do).

Comment: I already tried wrapping Qt inside of a Framework, but that doesn't work. The Framework won't compile, because Qt requires a _main function, which isn't available inside a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found another way to solve my initial problem with LGPL:

I'll give the possibility to download the compiled object files (mentioned in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395448/xcode-run-executable-file)) and other needed resources (like assets and xib files) of my solution along with instructions on how to build the actual app out of this.

This way all users will have the opportunity to build the app with their own version of Qt, without making my project open source or providing my source code.