# Xcode Run executable file

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I have a bunch of object (.o) files exported from a Swift project.
Then I ran:

```
clang -o MyApp.app -arch arm64 -isysroot $(xcrun --show-sdk-path) -bunch-of-frameworks-and-libraries-and-object-files

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign $identity --entitlements $xcentFile MyApp.app
```

And I got this MyApp.app program file out of it.
I know that other .app files, which are created while building an Xcode project, can be opened like a zip, but not this one.

What steps am I missing for "rebuilding" an app out of this file?

I have the original Xcode project and source codes, but I want to be able to build the app without using the original source code and I think this file I created out of the object files is the first step.

I created this file from every object file created from this Xcode project. Would it be possible to delete all .swift files and only use the new created file?

Comment: Look at the build log when you build the app using Xcode. Then you can see all of the commands and their arguments used to build the app. Then you can update your own build script to replicate what Xcode does.

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks for this Info. With xcodes build log I was finally able to sign the product of my object files the right way and run it on a device. I'll update this post soon to give a full solution to my initial problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got working solution now. I misunderstood the output of the clang command.
In my question I created a new file "MyApp.app" which lead to misunderstandig with the output file -> The output file is not a .app file/directory but an executable (which goes inside of a .app file/directory).
So I changed the command:

```
clang -o MyApp -arch arm64 -mios-version-min=14.0 \
-isysroot $(xcrun --show-sdk-path) \
$(find <path_to_object_files_folder> -name "*.o") \
-bunch-of-frameworks-and-libraries-and-object-files
```

Then I moved the created "MyApp" file to the .app directory of my projects "Product" folder.
This .app directory needs to be re-signed with something like

```
codesign --force --sign <signing identity> --entitlements <path_to_xcent_file> --timestamp\=none --generate-entitlement-der <path_to_app_directory>
```

(you can take the sign command from xcodes build log)

And voila, the .app file/directory could be deployed to my device.